# Rewrite of Custom Post Type doesn't work with dynamic data

Tags: custom-post-types, url-rewriting

I created a Custom Post Type in my plugin. I added an argument with rewrite:

```php
'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'foo/bar/%baz%', 'with_front' => false),
```

Then I added a method to replace `%baz%`:

```php
public function customPermalinks($post_link, $post)
{
    if (is_object($post) && $post->post_type == 'test') {
        $terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'baz');
        if ($terms) {
            return str_replace('%baz%', $terms[0]->slug, $post_link);
        }
    }
    return $post_link;
}
```

On `__construct()` I added this filter:

```
add_filter('post_type_link', [$this, 'customPermalinks'], 1, 2);
```

And... My CPT works only when I don't use dynamic variables (`%baz%`). When I remove `%baz%` from rewrite attribute, it works... Otherwise, I get a 404 message when I want to go to a single post. How to fix it?

I will add that before each change I manually refresh rewrite rules.

Here is my plugin file structure:

```php
class PluginName
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->createPostType();
        add_filter('post_type_link', [$this, 'customPermalinks'], 1, 2);
    }

    private function createPostType()
    {
        // arguments to my CPT
    }

    public function customPermalinks($post_link, $post)
    {
        // replace dynamic data from $post_link
    }
}

$pluginName = new PluginName();
```

Comment: Does `baz` belong to a registered object, or did you [add `baz` to the list of valid query vars](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars)?

Comment: @Milo `baz` is registered custom taxonomy. Variable `$post_link` returns a valid rewrite with `baz` value, ex. `foo/bar/lorem-ipsum/custom-post-title` but when I go at this address (the_permalink) it shows error with no post.

Comment: @Milo I forgot about `add_rewrite_tag('%baz%', '([^&/]+)');`. Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Well... I didn't know that the expressions in the `rewrite` attribute of CPT must be registered in advance:

```php
add_rewrite_tag('%baz%', '([^&/]+)');
```